# mapStateToProps to passing data to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

I'm building a staff rota system, I have a mapStateToProps function however the props rotaData is coming back as undefined 
This is my action:

```
import settings from '../../aws-config.js';
import Amplify, { Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';
export const GET_STAFF_SHIFTS = 'get_staff_shifts';
export function getShifts() {
console.log('Fetching list of shifts for user...');

const request = API.get("StaffAPI", "/shifts", {
headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }
});
return {
  type : GET_STAFF_SHIFTS,
  payload : request
 }
}
```

this is my reducer

```
import _ from "lodash"
import { GET_STAFF_SHIFTS} from '../actions';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
switch(action.type){
case GET_STAFF_SHIFTS:
    return { ...state, rotaData: action.payload.data };
 }
}
```

this is my mapStateToProps function

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
return{ rotaData: state.rotaData };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getShifts: getShifts}) 
(StaffRota);
```

However in my StaffRota class when console logging this.props, rotaData returns undefined.

Could any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[API.get()](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide#get) is **not** synchronous, instead it returns a Promise so you need to wait for it to finish, and then dispatch another action when the loading is finished. You need to install `redux-thunk` to be able to dispatch a function.

```
export const getShifts = () => dispatch => {
    const request = API.get("StaffAPI", "/shifts", {
        headers: {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then(response => 
        dispatch({type: 'SHIFTS_LOAD_SUCCESS', response})
    )
    .catch(err => 
        dispatch({type: 'SHIFTS_LOAD_FAIL'})
    )
}
```

You can then handle `SHIFTS_LOAD_SUCCESS` in your reducer which will contain the response. Then in your `mapDispatchToProps` you can provide the `getShifts` function to your component as props:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch => {loadAllShifts: dispatch(getShifts())})(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I then get an error stating Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: Yes you need to install [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#installation) to be able to dispatch async actions (there's instructions on the link on how to add it as your middleware)

Comment: Also [might be worth to read](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I have no clue what I am meant to be doing? I've install redux thunk

Comment: @SamuelGray 1. Change your `getShifts` like in my answer above 2. Write a reducer that handles `SHIFTS_LOAD_SUCCESS` and writes it to some place in the state 3. Write a `mapStateToProps` to extract data from the state 4. Write a `mapDispatchToProps` to make your `getShifts` available as the `loadAllShifts` prop to your component 5. Call `loadAllShifts` somewhere in your component. Your component will then re-render with the data as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

`API.get` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to use the resolved result instead.

You will also need use a library like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to delay the dispatching of the action until the API resolves.

```
const getShifts = () => dispatch =>
  API.get(...).then(response => dispatch({
    type: GET_STAFF_SHIFTS,
    payload: response,
  }))
```